# Passing reference to iterator with std::thread fails if container is not a reference in calling function

Tags: c++, multithreading, reference, stl, iterator

here is my problem:

I have a class with a container member, say a `std::vector`. I have a funtion, say `parallelStuff`, that takes *references* to iterators of this container and does stuff with it. I want to execute said function in parallel using `std::thread`

I have implemented this and it works fine. Now I wanted to write a very similar setup with one small difference: In the working version, in the function that invokes threads on `parallelStuff`, I get the iterators from a reference to the container.

If, however, I obtain the iterators from a non-reference container, compilation fails.

This is a working minimal example to replicate the issue:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {}
    auto const & member() { return member_; }
    void parallelStuff(std::vector<int>::const_iterator & it,
                       std::vector<int>::const_iterator const & end) {
        // do stuff while it != end
    }
private:
    std::vector<int> member_;
};


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    auto foo = Foo();
    auto& member = foo.member();
    // auto member = foo.member();  <-- copy instead of reference, this fails!
    auto it = member.begin();
    auto end = member.end();
    auto t = std::thread(&Foo::parallelStuff, &foo,
                         std::ref(it), std::ref(end));
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

As said, if I use a copy of `member` instead of a reference, I get the error

```
/usr/include/c++/8/thread:120:17: error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues
```

Googling the error message only led me to a [site](http://www.davidespataro.it/modern-c-concurrency-how-to-use-a-thread-object-correctly-and-common-pitfalls/) explaining that I need to wrap reference parameters in `std::ref()` which I already do.

Does anyone understand what is going wrong here and can please explain it (and how to fix this)?

Many thanks!

PS: Im using `gcc version 8.3.0 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.04)` with `-std=c++17`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `parallelStuff` expects to get *const iterators* and you have to provide them.

You can get *const iterators*:

1. by calling `cbegin`/`cend` on an object

or

2. by call `begin`/`end` on *const object*

In the line below

```
auto member = foo.member();
```

*auto type deduction* works which discards referenceness and constness from initializer. So `member` is just declared as `vector<int>`. So `begin`/`end` returns `vector<int>::iterator` what doesn't match to arguments of `parallelStuff`.

To get *const iterators* on non-const object just call `cbegin`/`cend`:

```
auto it = member.cbegin();
auto end = member.cend();
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/pbYLeJ)

---

This works

```
auto& member
```

because `member` is deduced to be `const vector<int>&`, so `begin` / `end` called on const object returns const iterators - `vector<int>::const_iterator` which matches to `parallelStuff` declaration.